# Sidebar doesn't show up

Tags: 7, routes, blocks

I've an problem displaying my sidebar...

I've build a custom block which has these settings:
[image]

And for display options, I've choose these:
[image]

But for some reason, the block doesn't appear in my sidebar on the page `jobs/BusinessAnalyst`. So what do I have to do to get this block into place?

Here is my custom .tpl file:

```
// Unset all the things we don't need
unset ($content['language']);
unset ($content['downloadable_documents']);
unset ($content['field_job_category']);
unset ($content['field_job_sub_category']);

// Finally, print the content (the ShareThis module)
print render($content);
```

I've checked, and the `$page['sidebar_left']` is empty.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the menu block module from your screenshot.  Is BusinessAnalyst actually part of any menu?  if not then I'm guessing that could be your problem.

Comment: That's the part part... I don't know in advance which pages are generated (and should get the block as menu), so hence the `jobs/*`...

Comment: But if that item isn't part of the menu tree, then it won't show up.  If Menu Block can't find it as part of the tree, then if I remember it won't display anything.  I may very well be wrong, it's been a while since I used that module.  Have you tried putting other blocks in the region? Just a simple hello world block or something to see if it displays?

Comment: Other blocks just show up fine. And whenever I create set the block to be visible on ALL pages, the block does show up too...

Comment: SO if you say to show on all pages, this block shows up on `jobs/BusinessAnalyst`

Comment: Yep. But when I specify to show on `jobs/*`, the block doesn't show up!